# Programmatically close all tabs in Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, autohotkey, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs, firefox-quantum

### 1. Summary

I can't find, how I can close all tabs in Firefox Quantum without any manual mouse clicks.

---

### 2. Details

*(Details for preventing [**XY Problem**](http://xyproblem.info/))*

I am working on several projects. I need always opened tabs for different projects (different tabs for different projects).

When I start working on one of my projects, I want automatically and quickly switch between projects: I press hotkey → all current browser tabs close → project-specific tabs open.

---

### 3. Requirements

#### 3.1. Types of tabs

These types of tabs also must be closed:

1. [**Pinned**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pinned-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open)
2. Current; [**`browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab` key value is `false` for me**](https://www.howtogeek.com/264880/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-exiting-when-you-close-the-last-tab/)

#### 3.2. Methods

Any methods, where user don't need to click manually to specific button are welcome. For example, it would be nice get expected behavior via any free:

1. Extension or script (for example, written in AutoHotkey), so that I can close all tabs via:

   1. Shortcut
   2. And/or [**underline access key shortcuts**](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97413-turn-off-underline-access-key-shortcuts-menus-windows-10-a.html) of Firefox menu or context menu
2. CLI commands

But click to specific buttons in Firefox toolbars is not expected. Reason — I don't find, how I can write the script, [**that can automatically clicks to specific button**](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/24163-click-button-on-firefox/) (but if you know, how do it, please, make an answer).

#### 3.3. No clicking to specific coordinates

Yes, for example, I can install [**`Close All Tabs Button`**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/close-all-button) extension → get `x` and `y` coordinates of this extension button → set via AutoHotkey automatically clicking to these coordinates.

But this is not better solution. I can:

1. Add, remove and move buttons in Firefox toolbar.
2. Resize Firefox windows.

Coordinates will be shifted in these cases.

#### 3.4. No auto-adding to groups

I tried some Firefox tabs organizers/tabs managers. They have a common non-expected behavior.

I created tab groups of my projects → I added required URLs for each group → I opened any new tabs in browser → this tabs automatically added to one of groups.

I don't need to automatically add random tabs to groups. Groups must contain a specific set of tabs; adding, editing and removing tabs of groups must be solely manually in my case.

#### 3.5. Stay in current Firefox profile

I can programmatically close Firefox → then open [**new Firefox instance with specific tabs**](https://askubuntu.com/a/617935/582218) as this:

```
firefox -P "SashaChernykh" --new-tab -url https://KiraGoddess.com --new-tab -url https://KiraGreatest.com
```

But in this case pinned tabs from previous session will be preserve in new instance.

I can't find, how I can solve this problem. Yes, I can open new tabs use new Firefox profile, but, possibly, it a not good idea. I'll have to configure and update settings, extensions, bookmarks and so on for each profile. Its additional work, whereas one profile is enough for me.

It would be nice close all tabs, stay in current Firefox profile.

---

### 4. Not helped

#### 4.1. Close all tabs extensions

4.1.1. Doesn't close pinned and current tabs

See 3.1 item, why it not expected.

1. [**Close All Tabs**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/close-all-tabs-webextension)

4.1.2. No hotkeys and/or menu items

See 3.2 item, why it not expected.

1. [**Close All Tabs Button**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/close-all-button)

4.1.3. Both

Both problems: `Doesn't close pinned and current tabs` and `No hotkeys and/or menu items`.

1. [**Tab Closer**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-closer)
2. [**Close All Tabs Button**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/close-all-tabs-button)

#### 4.2. Tabs organizers

4.2.1. Non-free

1. [**Toast**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dotoast)
2. [**Workona**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/workona)

4.2.2. Auto-adding to groups

I described this problem in 3.4 item.

1. [**Simple Tab Groups**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-tab-groups)
2. [**Tab Workspaces**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-workspaces)
3. [**Tab Manager**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-manager-webextension)
4. [**Power Tabs**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/power-tabs)
5. [**Panorama Tab Groups**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/panorama-tab-groups)
6. [**Tab Manager Plus for Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-manager-plus-for-firefox)
7. [**Conex**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/conex/)
8. [**Tab Group Switch**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-group-switch)

4.2.3. No hotkeys

Use these extensions, I can close all previous tabs and open new; but manual mouse clicks required. See 3.2 item for details.

1. [**Group Speed Dial**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/groupspeeddial)
2. [**Tab Stash**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-stash)

Comment: By _programatically_ you mean you'd like to do it from a script?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani , see 3.2 item of my question. Script — also it would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking something you already said, but, do you want to close all tabs AND leave Firefox core running, as in headless, in the background, or do you want to terminate all Firefox processes, hence closing all tabs, the UI, etc...? If the former, I'm not even sure it's possible with recent versions of Firefox, because the various processes are emmeshed way more closely than they used to be. If the latter, well, all you have to do is press Alt-F4, and Firefox will be history in Task Manager in a matter of seconds (a little bit more, actually, since it writes to disk before that).

Comment: @Didier , I want to close all tabs, that currently opened and then open other tabs ([**I know, what I need, that open specific tabs**](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/74818-how-to-launch-firefox-with-multiple-tabs/?p=475827). See details in item 2 of my question. Firefox *window* shouldn't be closed; *tabs* solely. Thanks for the question.

Comment: Is closing Firefox and its present set of tabs, to start it again with a fresh set of (different) tabs an option?

Comment: @Didier, yes it a good idea. But I have a problem. I close Firefox window → I open Firefox with specific tabs as described [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/a/617935/582218) → pinned tabs from previous session remain in new session. I don't find, how I can solve it. Sorry, I had to write it in my question. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to script that way, either in a batch file, or PowerShell. There are a few interesting command line commands/switches to be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options. All may not answer your question, but if you use the "-headless" switch, for example, you can close a window with a certain set of tabs, open another window with a fresh set of different tabs without having to close Firefox entirely. It's notoriously slow to load and unload to and from RAM...

Comment: @Didier, thanks, I read this article about Firefox command-line options before writing previous reply). But I can't find in it, how I can start Firefox without preserving pinned tabs from previous session. `-silent` and `new-instance` options not helped. Thanks.

Comment: You can do it in four steps: 1) Start Firefox "-headless"; 2) Open the first series of tabs via a batch file (with URLs separated by pipes); 3) Close current Firefox window with Alt-F4 or Ctrl-Shift-W (Firefox "core" *should* keep running in the background); 4) Open new set of different URLs in tabs with a second .bat file. EDIT: you can do 1) and 2) on the same .bat file.

Comment: Apparently, the "-silent" switch should work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AHK script works for me on firefox 74.0 (64-Bit), provided that the option
"**Show tab previews in the Windows taskbar**" in firefox Settings
is enabled:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
DetectHiddenWindows, On

#IfWinActive ahk_exe firefox.exe  ; only if firefox is the active window

    F1::
    title1 := ""      ; empty var
    title2 := ""
    title3 := ""    

    ; Close all but the active tab:
    WinGetTitle, title1, A
    WinGet, id, list, ahk_class MozillaTaskbarPreviewClass
    Loop, %id%
    {   
        this_ID := id%A_Index%  
        WinGetTitle, title2, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title2 != title1)
            WinClose, ahk_id %this_ID%
    }

    ; Close the active tab as soon as another tab gets active:
    SetTimer, CloseActiveTab, 1000  
    return

#IfWinActive

CloseActiveTab: 
If WinActive("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
{
    WinGetTitle, title3, A  
    If (title3 != title1)
    {
        SetTimer, CloseActiveTab, off       
        WinClose, %title1% ahk_class MozillaTaskbarPreviewClass
    }
}
return
```

**EDIT:**

Replace pseudo-array to object-based array in your modified script:

```
DetectHiddenWindows 1
WinActivate ahk_exe firefox.exe

~c & ~f::
Array := []
WinGet, KiraTabsNumber, List, ahk_class MozillaTaskbarPreviewClass
Loop %KiraTabsNumber% {
    Array.Push(KiraTabsNumber%A_Index%)
}
for index, element in Array
    WinClose ahk_id %element%
return
```

Comment: GEV, please, can you replace [**pseudo-array**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm#pseudo) to [**object-based array**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm#object-based)? For example, on [**line 36 of my modified script**](https://www.pastery.net/sakbyt/#l-36). Because pseudo-arrays not recommended to use. Thanks.

Comment: Your code closes the program but not all pinned tabs on my Firefox 74.0. Is that what you want to do? In that case you don't need to pusch elements in an array or a timer.

Comment: user3419297, `Your code closes the program but not all pinned tabs` — **no**, if modify Firefox settings. See [**line 6**](https://www.pastery.net/sakbyt/#l-6) of my modification of your script or 3.1.2 item of my question. Thanks.

Comment: See EDIT in this answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, `(KiraTabsNumber%A_Index%)` — is this definitely not an anti-pattern? Thanks.

Comment: It's the ID of the currenrt window in the Loop enumeration. If you add a message box in the For- Loop, you can see it.

Comment: Thanks; yes, I understand it. But my question — is `(KiraTabsNumber%A_Index%)` recommended coding-style practice; is this AutoHotkey [**anti-pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/980616/5951529)? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. A command's or a function's parameter can contain percent signs if its value is variabel.